# Web Component HTML y JS sin Frameworks

Tags: javascript, html, html5

Estoy empezando con web Components sin el uso de frameworks. tengo mi componente creado en un archivo JS

```js
class NavBar extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
      super();
      this.innerHTML = `
                        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark" role="navigation">
                            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                                <img src="static/imagenes/imagen.png" width="30" height="30"> ExpresSoftware
                            </a>
                            <div class="navbar-collapse justify-content-lg-end ml-5">
                                <ul class="navbar-nav nav-fill w-50 align-items-end">
                                    <li class="nav-item active">
                                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Nosotros</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="nav-item">
                                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Servicios</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="nav-item">
                                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Trabajos</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="nav-item">
                                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contacto</a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </nav>    
                       `;
    };
  };
  customElements.define('NavBar', NavBar);
```

Quiero llevar el código html de la propiedad InnerHTML a un html externo y poder solamente dar la ubicación del archivo html con ese código. 
Espero me puedan ayudar. Desde ya muchas gracias :)